# trigger backbone.js route without changing url

Tags: backbone.js

Here is my use case:

I have a bunch of images on the page, and each can be rated 1-5 stars.  I have a search that allows you to filter by a number of stars, which creates a url fragment like:

mydomain.com/app/#/stars/3

this is all working.  Now, lets say I change the rating on one of my images and filter again on 3 stars.  Because the url doesn't change my route doesn't fire, and my filtering doesn't occur.  I'm using:

```
window.router.navigate('#/' + url, true);
```

How would I trigger my routing function when the url doesn't change?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this - Backbone.history.loadUrl()

Comment: 'loadURL' method on history is not available in Backbone 1.0.0. Is there any other method to achieve this?

Comment: I checked backbone.js 1.0.0 sorce code - loadUrl method is exists